# Mudando a font-size do campo com valor vindo do banco

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript, css-font-size

Bom dia, eu recebo do banco de dados um vrFonte="x" com um valor x, esse valor que vem pra mim será o tamanho da fonte do input, é possível eu fazer o campo assumir o tamanho dessa fonte que vem do banco? se sim, como ? Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `[ngStyle]` como retorno de função, exemplo:

```
vrFonte: number
setStyles() {
  let styles = {
    'font-size': this.vrFonte || '13px'
  };
  return styles;
}

 //OBS: 'font-size': this.vrFonte || '13px' caso vrFonte seja `undefined` ele atribuira 13px ao input.
```

ai em seu input você colocaria :

```
<input type="text" [ngStyle]="setStyles()">
```

Outra forma de se fazer seria a usar o style bind do angular:

`<input type="text" [style.font-size.px]="{{ vrFonte }}">`

Comment: Deu certo, porém o valor não é alterado pq por padrão o ion-input tem um font-size !important, existe a opção de tirar esse important ou adicionar um a esse primeiro exemplo que mandou ?

Comment: Tente fazer:    'font-size': ``${this.vrFonte } !important``  , ou caso não venha o `'px'` junto do valor do banco use, 'font-size':     `${this.vrFonte }px !important` .

Comment: o px não vem junto, eu adicionei ele para funcionar, porém, quando coloco o !important não da certo